# jQuery Slide Panel Drag to Open function with mmenu plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a side project and I am trying to make a touch function to open the side panel on iPhone and Tablet. I am struggling really bad with this. I have tried a different file order in header. But it still doesn't work. I am no jQuery expert yet. If someone could tell me why my touch function doesn't work.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IBrcC

Any help is appreciated!

Edit!

Problem solved I tried go back some version of menu, and it seems to be a bug in 4.1.3 Version.

Comment: Bug should be fixed in version 4.1.6